# Convergence of $x^\beta \ln x$ using the fact that $x^{-\alpha}+\alpha \ln(x)-1>0$ with $0<\alpha<\beta$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$x^\beta \ln x$ clearly converges with L'Hôpital's rule by transforming $x^\beta \ln x$ into $\frac{\ln x}{x^{-\beta}}$. But I recently see a problem to show the convergence of $x^\beta \ln x$ by using the fact that $x^{-\alpha}+\alpha \ln(x)-1>0$ with $0<\alpha<\beta$. This seems to be a more fundamental way. I tried some computation, for example, from the given fact, I got $x^\alpha \ln x>\frac{x^\alpha-1}{\alpha}$ and $x^\alpha>e^{1-x^{-\alpha}}$. But it seems that none of them are giving useful information.

Comment: Convergence with respect to what and at what point? Please state the problem clearly in the main body of the question, we cannot read your mind.